# Installing ubuntu 16.04 problems

Tags: 16.04

I was using ubuntu 14.04 LTS for about 1 year, until suddenly a few drivers stopped working (i have no idea why), so i had to install ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I'm trying to install it from a usb (just like i installed the older version) and when it's starting the installing - it doesn't really do something. There is the install frame with the all new features of the new version. It says:
"Creating ext4file system for /in partition #1 of LVM VG ubuntu-vg, LV root..."

I opened the description of the installing and it seems that it doesn't really installing anything. Furthermore, the bar is always stuck (it never makes any progress of moving forward). In addition, it seems that it always fails in installing a few things during the installation because it says failed to do .... removing it.

In conclusion, I'm tired of this whole stupid system. I'm trying to move back to windows, although i don't like that system too and it doesn't work too. But, this ubuntu 16.04 is my last chance of having a working computer, please anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Try formatting the partition with gparted (in try Ubuntu mode) before installing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
   See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
   Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
   http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
2. Did you select the media check before trying to install?
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
3. Did you ever do a "memory check" (perhaps another live-media menu choice) on your PC?

Doing the above can save you a lot of time struggling with a bad install media or
hardware problems.